# Regular expression for full ISO 8601 date syntax

Tags: javascript, regex, iso8601

***Update:** Currently, a working solution has been achieved with multiple regular expressions used simultaneously*

I'm looking for a regular expression that covers the range of acceptable syntax for ISO 8601 dates. Most libraries and regex's only cover a subset or a "simplified" version of 8601, such as RFC 3339, but the full 8601 includes ways to express time durations and intervals. The wikipedia entry for ISO 8601 provides a good overview, but in short these should all be valid dates:

```
var testDates = {
    'year' : "2013",        
    'date' : "2013-01-05",
    'datetime' : "2013-01-05T04:13:00+00:00",
    'Duration only' : "P1Y2M10DT2H30M",
    'Week Duration' : "P1W",
    'Range with start and end' : "2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/2008-05-11T15:30:00Z",
    'Range of Date/Duration' : "2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/P1Y2M10DT2H30M",
    'Range of Date/Duration 1 month' : "2012-10/P1M",
    'Range of Date/Duration 1 week' : "2012-10/P1W",
    'Range of Duration/Date' : "P1Y2M10DT2H30M/2007-03-01T13:00:00Z", 
    'Repeating interval 5 times' : "R5/2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/P1Y2M10DT2H30M", 
    'Repeating interval weekly indefinitely' : "R/2012-10/P1W",
    'Repeating interval monthly 5 times' : "R5/2012-10/P1M"
}
```

I'm trying to build a regular expression that will cover all these possibilities. I've pieced a few components together, but am not skilled enough with regular expressions to make them all work as one expression and cover all possible cases. Just doing a simple "OR" between these doesn't seem to work as expected, but perhaps I'm not doing it quite right.

The expressions I've tried include these:

```
var regex = {
    'Date' : /^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$/,
    'Duration' : /^P(?=\w*\d)(?:\d+Y|Y)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+W|W)?(?:\d+D|D)?(?:T(?:\d+H|H)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+(?:\­.\d{1,2})?S|S)?)?$/,      
    'Range of Date/Date' : /^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?(\/)([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$/,      
    'Range of Date/Duration' : /^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?(\/)P(?=\w*\d)(?:\d+Y|Y)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+W|W)?(?:\d+D|D)?(?:T(?:\d+H|H)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+(?:\­.\d{1,2})?S|S)?)?$/,
    'Range of Duration/Date' : /^P(?=\w*\d)(?:\d+Y|Y)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+W|W)?(?:\d+D|D)?(?:T(?:\d+H|H)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+(?:\­.\d{1,2})?S|S)?)?\/([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$/,
    'Repeating interval' : /^R\d*\/([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?\/P(?=\w*\d)(?:\d+Y|Y)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+W|W)?(?:\d+D|D)?(?:T(?:\d+H|H)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+(?:\­.\d{1,2})?S|S)?)?$/
}
```

I've put together an example script that tries these expressions on each of the dates listed above, but if anyone could provide guidance on combining all these cases into one expression, it would be much appreciated.

The use case that's driving this is to validate an ISO 8601 Date for a JSON Schema document. JSON Schema does provide some flexibility in how something is validated in that you can provide multiple rules or regular expressions to test. In this case, I could solve my problem by using multiple regular expressions rather than one combined expression.

**Update:** the problem has been addressed so far by using this approach (multiple separate expressions used simultaneously)

<del>If I were to do that, then the one case which I have not solved is a range that starts with a duration and then specifies an end date (Range of Duration/Date)

All the expressions noted before are actually just different combinations of two expressions, one for a datetime and another for a duration. 

The only one I've been unable to validate properly is "Range of Duration/Date"</del>

Here's the script:

- As a gist: https://gist.github.com/philipashlock/8830168
- As a webpage: http://bl.ocks.org/philipashlock/raw/8830168/

Comment: Interesting question and I'll be curious to see your final answer. However, I would strongly suggest writing these (non-trivial) regexes in free spacing mode with indentation and comments so that it is readable by mere mortals (even though JavaScript does not support the x-modifier). With JS's no-x-mode-limitation, I like to include the verbose regex inside a multi-line comment immediately preceeding the actual RegExp literal.

Comment: I've updated the description to note that all of these expressions are just different combinations of two expressions (one for date and one for duration) and there's only one combination that does not currently work. I've also updated the gist with references to the source of those two expressions where there's some additional explanation of how they were constructed.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the full set of expressions I've found to achieve the variety of ISO 8601 syntax. The [gist](https://gist.github.com/philipashlock/8830168) has been updated with these and additional tests for repeating intervals.

```
var regex = {
    'Date' : /^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$/,
    'Duration' : /^P(?=\w*\d)(?:\d+Y|Y)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+W|W)?(?:\d+D|D)?(?:T(?:\d+H|H)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+(?:\­.\d{1,2})?S|S)?)?$/,      
    'Range of Date/Date' : /^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?(\/)([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$/,      
    'Range of Date/Duration' : /^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?(\/)P(?=\w*\d)(?:\d+Y|Y)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+W|W)?(?:\d+D|D)?(?:T(?:\d+H|H)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+(?:\­.\d{1,2})?S|S)?)?$/,
    'Range of Duration/Date' : /^P(?=\w*\d)(?:\d+Y|Y)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+W|W)?(?:\d+D|D)?(?:T(?:\d+H|H)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+(?:\­.\d{1,2})?S|S)?)?\/([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$/,
    'Repeating interval' : /^R\d*\/([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?\/P(?=\w*\d)(?:\d+Y|Y)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+W|W)?(?:\d+D|D)?(?:T(?:\d+H|H)?(?:\d+M|M)?(?:\d+(?:\­.\d{1,2})?S|S)?)?$/
}
```

Comment: A modification to the date regex that captures strictly what you need for parsing the date. Note that `24:00` is not captured, but it is effectively the same as no time so any parser should handle it the same. `/^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))(?:(-?)(?:(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:\2([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))(?:[T\s](?:(?:([01]\d|2[0-3])(?:(:?)([0-5]\d))?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(?:\10([0-5]\d)([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-](?:[01]\d|2[0-3])):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$/`

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to question the full approach. Dates, instants, and ranges are *different* concepts, accepting them interchangeably (what I understand from wanting a single regular expression for all of them) will lead to user, programmer, or (even worse) both error.

If the allowed formats are too complex, *somebody* will make mistakes. Can't your application work with a subset?

Answer (score 0):

Is a regex the best/most appropriate solution for this?

It appears that you're really trying to parse a string according to the spec. Just look at how complex some of those regexes are that you've tried.

My suggestion would be either to make simpler regexes that match each pattern mixed in with some if/then code or to use/create a full on parser.

Remember that regexes were designed for pattern matching, not parsing. They're great for pulling out a quick value from a string but not for more complex things.

Comment: I'm actually not trying to parse it, just validate it. This is being used within a JSON Schema document (http://json-schema.org/), so it's meant to be language agnostic using just a regex.

Comment: In which case i'd create a regex for each pattern and tell the reader to appply all of them instead of one mega expression that tries to cover them all and is unreadable.

What does having a single regex give you that 6 smaller and easier to understand regexes won't give you? Other than thinking you have one uber regex that will do everything.

Comment: Fortunately, JSON Schema does allow you to define multiple possible validation rules, so I think I could in fact do that in the context of JSON Schema. In that case, I think the only regex I'm missing is one that properly combines dates and durations within a range. I'll work on that and provide an update here.

Comment: I've updated the description and the gist to suggest this approach. Right now, I'm just missing a working regular expression for one of the permutations of the two combined expressions (a range with a duration/date).

Comment: You should realise that, even with those complex regexes, you'll still get false positives. `2014-02-31` is not a valid date but will match, and the same goes for `2014-04-31`.

Comment: That's ok, the main focus is to validate the ISO 8601 syntax