# DateInterval failed with decimal number

Tags: php, time, iso

I have a duration in ISO format witch I need to convert it into seconds number. I use the function `DateInterval` to extract `years, mounths, days, hours, minutes and seconds` and convert its into seconds. But I have a problem: when the duration in format ISO Contains only `int` number(PT2M2S), the `DateInterval` function works perfectly but when  the duration contains decimal number(PT2M2.6S) the `DataInterval` function does'nt work.

Exemple: $session_time = `"PT2M2S";`
when I use `DataInterval`:

```
`$interval = new DateInterval($session_time);` 
$sessionTimeBySeconde = $interval->y*525600*60 + $interval->m*43800*60 + $interval->h*3600 + $interval->i*60 + $interval->s;
```

In this cas it works perfectly.

Now if I have for exemple : $session_time = `"PT2M2.6S";` 
and if I use DataInterval like above :

```
`$interval = new DateInterval($session_time);` 
$sessionTimeBySeconde = $interval->y*525600*60 + $interval->m*43800*60 + $interval->h*3600 + $interval->i*60 + $interval->s;
```

In this cas it does'nt work..

For Information I don't responsible for the value `$session_time`, I juste get it form another system and I want to convert it into seconds.

What I can do ?

Comment: `"PT2M2.6S"` is bad format, so it wont work. You should debug with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions thank you for your response, you confirme my doubts... unfortunately I'm not responsible for this value, it is an another system which send me this value... Do you have an idea about what I can resolve this problem ?

Comment: Not really, maybe the is an regex that can validate a format that looks like `PT2M2S` before using it with DateIntervall, but what you do if an invalid was detected is on you.

Comment: thank you , I will try to use a regex :)

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686539/regular-expression-for-full-iso-8601-date-syntax    this was an topic before

Answer (score 0):

The year is 2024! And currently this yet a PHP problem.

How you can see on this bug onpened (and closed without solution) https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53831.

But the great news (not so great because this workaround dated from 2012) is the following:

```
class DateIntervalFractions extends DateInterval {
    public $milliseconds;
    public function __construct($interval_spec) {
        $this->milliseconds = 0;
        $matches = array();
        preg_match_all("#([0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]*)[S]#",$interval_spec,$matches);
        foreach ($matches[0] as $result)
        {
            $original = $result;
            list($seconds,$milliseconds) = explode(".",substr($result,0,-1));
            $this->milliseconds = $milliseconds / pow(10,strlen($milliseconds) - 3);

            // Replace the milliseconds back to seconds,
            // and let the original constructor do the rest.
            $interval_spec = str_replace($original,$seconds . "S",$interval_spec);
        }
        parent::__construct($interval_spec);
    }
}
```

This worked perfectly for me! thanks jdp2234 at hotmail dot com, your comment on php bug track saved me!